# Using external files in WebView

Tags: android, file, webview

Is it possible to refer to an external file [not present in the res/raw folder of the app] in a WebView? The documentation [and the StackOverflow questions] I've read so far doesn't deal with this question.

Can I load an image on external storage, say /sdcard/abc.jpg using the img tag and the loadData() method of a WebView? I've tried doing that, but the image is not displayed. Another example would be a .js file on external storage being used with a WebView. Is this possible, or is WebView restricted to referring only to local files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a url like `content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/abc.jpg`

(edit: add "file" in url, and removed line about me only testing in the browser app...works fine in a WebView)